# Open command doesn't like non escaped characters even between quotes?

Tags: terminal, command-line

Is it me or the `open` command does only accept escaped characters in parameters ?

It tried `open "~/Library/Messages/Attachments/87/07/079C263B-0586-48C6-B721-3C6AABAC76DF/Messages Image(1020754653).jpeg"`

which returns `The file /Users/Kyro/Library/Messages/~/Library/Messages/Attachments/87/07/079C263B-0586-48C6-B721-3C6AABAC76DF/Messages Image(1020754653).jpeg does not exist.`

When actually `open /Users/Kyro/Library/Messages/Attachments/87/07/079C263B-0586-48C6-B721-3C6AABAC76DF/Messages\ Image\(1020754653\).jpeg` works quite well.

Edit : Running Mavericks here.

Comment: open "./a b/1.txt" works for me (OSX 10.9)

Comment: Well yeah your right, here too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not `open`, it's the fact that `~` only works when it's not in quotes. `~` isn't actually part of a standard file path, it's a shell metacharacter that the shell replaces in contexts where it looks like the beginning of a path (and quotes suppress this). Here are some examples:

```
$ echo ~
/Users/gordon
$ echo "~"
~
$ ls ~/Library
Accounts        Fonts Disabled      Printers
[...]
$ ls "~/Library"
ls: ~/Library: No such file or directory
```

Note the last command above: since `~` is inside double-quotes, it doesn't get replaced by the path to my home folder, and then `ls` just treats is as a normal filename (that happens not to exist). The same thing is happening in your `open` command.

Since the file you're actually trying to open has other shell metacharacters in its name, what you should do is partially-quote the path: leave the `~` outside the quotes, but make sure the filename part is inside quotes. Something like this:

```
open ~/"Library/Messages/Attachments/87/07/079C263B-0586-48C6-B721-3C6AABAC76DF/Messages Image(1020754653).jpeg"
```

Answer (score 2):

Well I did not read correctly the output of the error.

`open` is one hell of a *****.

It adds the working directory ahead of the command when using quotes.

`/Users/Kyro/Library/Messages/~/Library/Messages/` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Alright, so you have solved your problem then, right?

Answer (score 1):

As an appendix to @Gordon Davidsons answer:

From the [Bash Man Page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sh.1.html):

EXPANSION

> Expansion is performed on the command line after it has been split
>   into words.  There are seven kinds of  expansion  performed: brace
>   expansion, tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, command
>   substitution, arithmetic expansion, word splitting, and pathname
>   expansion.

Tilde Expansion

> If a word begins with an unquoted tilde character (`~'), all of the
>   characters  preceding  the  first unquoted  slash (or all characters,
>   if there is no unquoted slash) are considered a tilde-prefix.  If none
>   of the characters in the tilde-prefix are quoted, the characters in
>   the  tilde-prefix  following the  tilde are treated as a possible
>   login name.  If this login name is the null string, the tilde is
>   replaced with the value of the shell parameter HOME.  If HOME is
>   unset, the  home  directory  of  the user  executing  the  shell is
>   substituted instead.  Otherwise, the tilde-prefix is replaced with the
>   home directory associated with the specified login name.
>
> If the tilde-prefix is a `~+', the value of the shell variable PWD
>   replaces the tilde-prefix.  If the tilde-prefix is a`~-', the value
>   of the shell variable OLDPWD, if it is set, is substituted.  If the
>   characters following the tilde in the tilde-prefix consist of a number
>   N, optionally  prefixed  by  a `+'  or  a`-', the tilde-prefix is
>   replaced with the corresponding element from the directory stack, as
>   it would be displayed by the dirs builtin invoked with the
>   tilde-prefix as an  argument.   If  the characters  following the
>   tilde in the tilde-prefix consist of a number without a leading `+' or`
>   -', `+' is assumed.
>
> If the login name is invalid, or the tilde expansion fails, the word
>   is unchanged.
>
> Each variable assignment is checked for unquoted tilde-prefixes
>   immediately  following  a  :  or  the first  =.   In  these cases,
>   tilde expansion is also performed.  Consequently, one may use file
>   names with tildes in assignments to PATH, MAILPATH, and CDPATH, and
>   the shell assigns the expanded value.